# why the git author contains password in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

When I using Intellij Idea to develop, the author comment show the committer's password. Why the password show in the author comment when the author commit code? how to hide the password? The password looks like :

[image]

the red area was the committer's password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDE shows the Git commit author here. So it seems that the commit's author name contains the password string.

You can click the author name in the editor to show the commit list in the editor's left gutter, then click that related commit in the editor's left gutter, check the detailed commit's user name there to see that some password was used in the commit author name there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably entered yor password instead your email address in the dialog for git. See same issue here:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000169244-Clear-text-password-displayed-in-author-column

I hope JetBrains changes that because it seems to be many people (including me) that had the same problem